# Same Webpart added multiple times on a Site page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, webpart-connection

I have 2 instances of same webpart deployed on same page.

Webpart has a property named Network, which will take values Internal or External.

Webpart1 is setup as internal. and Network on WebPart2 is setup as external.

After adding webpart, on any event on first webpart is working fine. Any event on Second Webpart shows Network value as Internal. It works fine if I remove the first webpart from the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share your code related to the Web Part Property in order to give a solution.

One possible scenario might be that the property or encapsulated field might have been declared as static in the web part source.